# call empty function with address of local variable before setjmp, what for?

Tags: c, setjmp

I read code of C library and can not understand what is going on:

```c
struct Foo *foo = NULL;
lib_var((void *)&foo);
if (setjmp(get_jmp_buf()) == 0) {
  foo = ...;
  // other calculation that may cause longjmp
} else {
  //something bad happens
  drop_if_not_null(foo);
}
```

where `lib_var` is function that has such prototype `void lib_var(void *);`,
and such implementation in separate C file:

```
void lib_var(void *variable)
{
// nothing
}
```

So what for `lib_var` function, something like `volatile` to force compiler reread variable from memory in `setjmp() != 0` case?
Is this undefined behavior? Because of I am sure LTO remove such completely useless code,
and LTO should not change behavior of confirming to standard code.

Comment: Where did you find this?  The `setjmp` function expects a parameter of type `jmp_buf`.

Comment: It does look like a (possibly misguided) attempt to ensure that `foo` will be allocated in memory rather than a register, and thus have its value preserved through the `longjmp` and reloaded afterwards.  I agree that `volatile` would be the proper way to do this.

Comment: @dbush `setjmp` call is pseudocode, I removed usage of `context` variable where is help of utility method `jmp_buf` was extracted

Comment: `I read code of C library` Why not tells us which C library is that? Is it opensource? Can you post a link to the snippet? Could you post full real code? Do you know the author of that code - why not ask him? Is  the code in source control version? Does the commit history tell something? Was the code maintained by multiple people? We only know what you tell us, so if you give only information that are needed to only get the conclusions that you got, we will all get the same conclusions... ie. we'll learn almost nothing new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's undefined behavior from the standpoint of standard C - or at least, the value of `foo` is indeterminate and can't be safely used for anything.

C17 (n2176) 7.13.2.1 (3):

> All accessible objects have values, and all other components of the abstract machine have state,
> as of the time the longjmp function was called, except that the values of objects of automatic storage
> duration that are local to the function containing the invocation of the corresponding setjmp macro
> that do not have volatile-qualified type and have been changed between the setjmp invocation and
> longjmp call are indeterminate.

That's precisely the situation here: `foo` has automatic storage duration and is local to the function where `setjmp` is invoked, it's not `volatile`-qualified, and it is changed between `setjmp` and `longjmp`.

The authors of the code were probably thinking that passing `&foo` to `lib_var` would ensure that it is allocated in memory, not in a register, and that since the compiler couldn't know whether `lib_var` would modify `foo`, it couldn't constant-propagate the value `NULL` into the `else` block.  But as you say, LTO or various other optimizations could break this.  It's possible the authors intended only to support a particular compiler that they knew didn't do any such thing, or that provided some stronger guarantees beyond what the standard says, but it's also possible they were just confused.

The correct fix would be to declare `foo` as `volatile`, i.e. `struct Foo * volatile foo = NULL;`.